# Foundation SCSS compile error but everything works?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am using the scss version of Foundation and using Grunt to compile everything. I am getting errors in compiling, but everything seems to work?

For example:

`@include clearfix();` throws an error saying `Undefined mixin 'clearfix'.` but I am getting the desired result.

`@extend .show-for-small;` throws an error saying 
`(Line 4: ".loan-calculator .loan-calc-small" failed to @extend ".show-for-small".
The selector ".show-for-small" was not found.
Use "@extend .show-for-small !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.)` but again I am getting the desired result.

Its as though the errors are wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has this just started happening in an existing project? Or has it always done this?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't start my filename for the partial with an underscore